# Can you use a class inside of a function in C#

Tags: class, function, c#

I was wondering if I could use a class inside of a function.  I would the call the function in another file using     using filename.FuntionName();     I made the class public so that it would more likely cooperate.  Also, would     using filename.FunctionName();  call the function from the other file, or just use it as a resource?  Well, here is the code:

```
namespace file
{
public void file()
{
    public class file
    {
        /*function
        code*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, but also you can't declare a function outside of a class. Why not simply switch the placement of the class and function declarations?

Comment: @JoshC.: yeah, I am still not clear about what OP is trying to do and why having a class inside a function makes sense / is beneficial etc.

Comment: @user1733537: that would be akin to asking, "can I put a directory inside of my file?"

Answer (score 2):

You cant declare classes inside functions like `Java` , however you can use `var` to create an anonymous type that are not visible outside the function

```
  void file()
    {
        var file=new {
            path="path",
            size=200};
        Console.WriteLine(file.path+"  "+file.size);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you're looking for is a **static** method.

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static void CallMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call `SomeNameSpace.SomeClass.CallMe()` from elsewhere without having to create a new instance of `SomeClass`.

Comment: @user1733537 So your question was actually "Can you use a function inside a class?" That's the opposite of what you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to declare a function:

```
namespace Company.Utilities.File
{
    public class File
    {
        public File(string filename)
        {
           Filename = filename;
        }

        public string Filename { get; private set; }

        public void Process()
        {
            // Some code to process the file.
        }

        public static void ProcessFile(string filename)
        {
            File file = new File(filename);
            file.Process();
        }
    }
}
```

The point with the long namespace name is that it should be unique even when using assemblies from other companies (Third Part assemblies)

If you want to call the class like it was a function you should create a static function (like ProcessFile) then you can call File.ProcessFile(filename);

Comment: Well, my goal, is to call a function from another file.  I have a file with a database of functions under a namespace.  I want to be able to call those functions from from my other .cs files in my executable.  I thought maybe I could use the file name or namespace as aresource and freely call the function from within a namespace.  I will fix the class inside a function thing though, I will change the private void file function to namespace file and use the namespace, but then how would I call the class like I would a function?